# import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.layout.HtmlPageHeader;

Tags: javascript, java, itext, itext7

```java
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.layout.HtmlPageHeader; import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;

HtmlPageHeader header = new HtmlPageHeader();
header.setScript("../../hisglobal/js/jquery-main.min.js");
document.add(header);
```

but I'm not able to find a jar with this, where I can import these imports.
I have tried I io-7.1.9, and itext 5.*.*  jar
not html2pdf 7.2.0  where I can download this jar and use it without error.

Comment: Please take a look at this article: https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/installing-itext-pdfhtml-for-java-developers

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, but I'm not using  maven so that's why I'm not able to do I need jar itext7.. but it's not available

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addHeader(HtmlTags.JAVASCRIPT, "function addScript(){\r\n" +
                    "   var script = document.createElement('script');\r\n" + 
                    "   script.type= \"text/javascript\";\r\n" + 
                    "    script.src = '../../hisglobal/js/jquery-main.min.js';\r\n" + 
                    "    document.body.appendChild(script);\r\n""}");


document.setJavaScript_onLoad("addScript();");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).